# Totalling inner lists by different methods on a list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm not too experienced with Linq, and I'm having trouble working out the best approach for the following.

I have a list of items, each of which has 2 lists as properties. I've posted a non-Linq solution for what I'm trying to do. Both of the inner lists have a type property I need to filter on. One should add one to the total per item, the other has an amount property instead.

```
IEnumerable<Foo> foos = /*a list of foo*/;
Dictionary<Foo, int> totals = new Dictionary<Foo, int>();
foreach (Foo foo in foos)
{
    int total = 0;
    foreach(Bar1 bar in foo.Bar1)
    {
        if (bar.Type == selectedBarType)
        {
            total += bar.Amount;
        }
    }
    foreach(Bar2 bar in foo.Bar2)
    {
        if (bar.Type == selectedBarType)
        {
            total++;
        }
    }
    totals[foo] = total;
}
```

**How would I do this as cleanly as possible using Linq?**

---

- Pre post edit:
  I suppose I could add a method to foo that simply exposed the total filtered by type for each Foo, rendering this trivial. I'll post this question anyway because I'm curious as to the best approach to solving this in one.

Comment: I believe you have typo in the code, `totlas[foo] = total` not `bar`?

Comment: Quite right, thanks Michael - fixed

Comment: You can use IEnumerable extension method like Where(), Sum() instead of foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must work:

```
 Dictionary<Foo, int> totals = foos.ToDictionary(x => x,
          y => y.Select(z => new  
          {
              Sum1 = z.Bar1.Where(d => d.Type == selectedBarType).Sum(d => d.Amount),
              Sum2 = z.Bar2.Where(d => d.Type == selectedBarType).Sum(d => d.Amount)
          }).Sum());
```

Comment: This looks good - I like the use of a Select().Sum() to bring the 2 totals together. Thanks, accepted.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is:

```
var totals =             foos.ToDictionary(f => f, f => { return 
              f.Bar1.Where(b1 => b1.Type == selectedBarType).Sum(b1 => b1.Amount)
            + f.Bar2.Count(b2 => b2.Type == selectedBarType); });
```